# Unable to import Pandas_Datareader

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm using Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 16.04.

From this very simple program:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
amzn = web.DataReader("AMZN", "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2015,1,1))
```

I get this very impressive error list:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/SAT/time_series.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas_datareader.data as web
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 3, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 146, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from unittest import TestCase
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
from .main import TestProgram, main
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 4, in <module>
import argparse
File "/SAT/argparse.py", line 1
if len(sys.argv) &gt; 1:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've really now idea what is causing this error other than it's occurring when the program tries to import pandas_datareader.

I am new to the data_reader but I'm pretty sure the import command is syntactically correct.

Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Comment: `&gt;` - this looks like a broken Numpy. Why `>` got converted to `&gt;`? Or is it your IDE that did this conversion?

Comment: Yes, as @MaxU mentioned it seems like you have a SyntaxError in `SAT/argparse.py`.  Doesn't seem to be a pandas-datareader issue.

Comment: @ Brad Solomon When I type that command in terminal the system hung for a while but ultimately returned nothing. I added it by hand though to my project in pycharm its version 0.5.0 and is listed as one of the included packages.

Comment: `argparse.py` in your SAT directory seems to be interfering with the actual argparse module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have shadowed Python module `argparse` with your own `/SAT/argparse.py`.

`/anaconda/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py` in line 4 tries to import `argparse` (the standard Python module), but your module (which has an error `len(sys.argv) &gt; 1:`) jumps in first.

Try to rename `/SAT/argparse.py` to `/SAT/my_argparse.py`

PS try to name your own scripts and directories differently so that they don't shadow stardard Python  modules

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
import datetime

import pandas_datareader.data as web

amzn = web.DataReader("AMZN", "yahoo", datetime.datetime(2000,1,1), datetime.datetime(2015,1,1))
```

Comment: `datetime` has nothing to do with the traceback shown in the question.  The issue is with the pandas-datareader import or `SAT/argparse.py` more likely.

Comment: Apologies I did accidentally remove the import datetime when pasting the minimal example. As Brad Solomon says though it has nothing to do with the problem.